# Show stdout and stderr in Zenith

Tags: bash, shell-script, linux-mint, nemo, zenity

I am trying to install `.deb` file by right clicking on it in Nemo.

My Nemo Action Looks like:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Install Deb File
Comment=Install %F
Exec=<scripts/install_deb_file.sh %F>
Icon-Name=package-x-generic-symbolic
Selection=s
Extensions=deb;
EscapeSpaces=true
Dependencies=zenity;dpkg;
```

My `zenity_askpass.sh` file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --password --title="Authenticate"
```

My `install_deb_file.sh` file looks like:

```
#!/bin/dash

export SUDO_ASKPASS="$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/scripts/zenity_askpass.sh"
sudo dpkg -i "$1"
```

How can I modify `install_deb_file.sh` so that it install the `.deb` package and show the stdout / stderr of `sudo dpkg -i "$1"` in zenity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `install_deb_file.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/dash

export SUDO_ASKPASS="$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/scripts/zenity_askpass.sh"

# zenity --notification --text="$(sudo dpkg -i "$1" 2>&1)"

# zenity --width=250 --height=250 --info --text="$(sudo dpkg -i "$1" 2>&1)"

COMMAND_OUTPUT=$(sudo dpkg -i "$1" 2>&1)

if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    zenity --info --width=250 --text="$COMMAND_OUTPUT"
    exit 1
else
    notify-send --expire-time=200000 "Successfully Installed $1"
    exit 0
fi
```